# How to deserialize the ProtoBuf serialized HBase columns in Hive?

Tags: hive, hbase, protocol-buffers, hive-serde, protobuf-java

I have used ProtoBuf's to serialize the class and store in HBase Columns. 
I want to reduce the number of Map Reduce jobs for simple aggregations, so I need SQL like tool to query the data. 
If I use Hive, Is it possible to extend the HBaseStorageHandler and write our own Serde for each Table?
Or any other good solution to is available.

### Updated:

I created the HBase table as

> create 'hive:users' , 'i'

and inserted user data from java api,

```
 public static final byte[] INFO_FAMILY = Bytes.toBytes("i");
 private static final byte[] USER_COL = Bytes.toBytes(0);
 public Put mkPut(User u)
    {
        Put p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(u.userid));
        p.addColumn(INFO_FAMILY, USER_COL, UserConverter.fromDomainToProto(u).toByteArray());
        return p;
    }
```

my scan gave results as:

```
hbase(main):016:0> scan 'hive:users'
ROW                                COLUMN+CELL
 kim123                            column=i:\x00, timestamp=1521409843085, value=\x0A\x06kim123\x12\x06kimkim\x1A\x10kim123@gmail.com
1 row(s) in 0.0340 seconds
```

When I query the table in Hive, I don't see any records.
Here is the command I used to create table.

```
create external table users(userid binary, userobj binary) 
stored by 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' 
with serdeproperties("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key, i:0", "hbase.table.default.storage.type" = "binary") 
tblproperties("hbase.table.name" = "hive:users");
```

when I query the hive table I don't see the record inserted from hbase.

Can you please tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: you're column mapping might be broken - try removing the space, like `:key,i:0`. Otherwise it looks ok and should work IMO.

Comment: Thanks @botchniaque , I removed the spaces while creating the table. My `select * from users` returned 0 records, where as `select count(*) from users` returned count as 1 and `select users.userid from users` gave an IOException. `Error: java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Error evaluating userid (state=,code=0)`

Comment: Do you have access to hive-server logs? From experience they provide more useful details then those popping up to user interface. Try `/var/log/hive/hive-server2.log` or something.

Comment: One more thing - you use byte `x00` for your column, but the `hbase.columns.mapping` seems to be text based. Maybe try to write column ASCII `0`. Your should call `Bytes.toBytes("0")` in that case (zero as character, and not byte number). Maybe that's the problem

Comment: I tried with Bytes.toBytes("0"), still not seeing the data in beeline cli, may be its because binary. But I am sure data is mapped because it is showing the count correctly, I will write a simple udf  to convert binary to string, keep the post updated. Thanks @botchniaque

Comment: I wrote an UDF to deserialize and it worked fine with the column name being string 0 i.e Bytes.toBytes("0"), but if I have column names like byte[] COL_QUAL= new byte[] { 0 }; the mapping is not working and my udf is not getting called. Can you please tell me how to solve this one? @botchniaque

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try writing a UDF which would take binary protobuf and convert it to some readable structure (comma separated or json). You would have to make sure to map values as binary data.

Comment: I updated the question for more details. Can you help me with this? @botchniaque

Comment: I could able to deserialize the protobuf from udf and return a json, so that it can be further handled from get_json_object and get_tuple @botchniaque thanks a lot